# FTP file from ANT task: Windows Server to Windows 10 remote m/c

Tags: batch-file, ant, ftp

I'm trying to send a zip file from my Windows server m/c(Path: D:/build/scripts/test)to Windows10 machine (D:/Zip_upload) by using ANT Task. For test purpose, I'm currently sending a test.txt placed at (Path: D:/build/scripts/test) with HelloWord written in it.

I have created a folder called D:/Zip_upload and enabled FTP on my Windows 10 machine.
I can do ftp from server m/c to windows10 by cmd

```
D:\build\scripts\test>ftp 10.190.66.21
Connected to 10.190.66.21.
220 Microsoft FTP Service
200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
User (10.190.66.21:(none)): build
331 Password required
Password:
230 User logged in.
ftp> put test.txt
200 PORT command successful.
125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 12 bytes sent in 0.37Seconds 0.03Kbytes/sec.
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful.
125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
test.txt
226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 13 bytes received in 0.00Seconds 13000.00Kbytes/sec.
```

Below is my ant task that I wrote.

```
    <target name="test">
    <ftp 
            server="10.190.66.21"
            userid="build" password="diet4pizz@"
            remotedir="D:/Zip_upload/"
            action="send"
            verbose="yes"
            binary="no"
            >
            <fileset dir="./../scripts/test/">
              <include name="text.txt"/>
            </fileset>
    </ftp>
```

I have tried passing **remotedir="D:/Zip_upload"** as the Windows 10 remote m/c path. But had no success and it throws me error as :

```
Buildfile: D:\build\scripts\build.xml

test:

BUILD FAILED
D:\build\scripts\build.xml:611: could not change remote directory: 550 The parameter is incorrect.


Total time: 0 seconds
```

When I pass **remotDir="/D/Zip_upload/"**  then

```
D:\build.toolkit.V10\scripts>ant test
Buildfile: D:\build\scripts\build.xml

test:

BUILD FAILED
D:\build\scripts\build.xml:614: could not change remote directory:550 The system cannot find the path specified.


Total time: 0 seconds
```

When I pass **remotDir="/"**  then it does not throw error but does not even sends the file.

```
D:\build\scripts>ant test
Buildfile: D:\build\scripts\build.xml

test:
      [ftp] sending files
      [ftp] 0 files sent

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Request you to please help me out here, what should i do in this case or what I'm doing wrong to resolve it & send the file successfully.
I cannot do linux machine, i need to do from Windows server to Windows 10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you cannot specify the drive letter as you are not connecting using unc, it is ftp so it needs to be something like: `remotedir="/pub/incoming"`

Comment: Gerhard, i followed : https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html -- Sending files section -- and saw example as below :
```
<ftp server="ftp.nt.org"
     remotedir="c:\uploads"
     userid="coder"
     password="java1"
     separator="\"
     verbose="yes">
    <fileset dir="htdocs/manual">
        <include name="**/*.html"/>
    </fileset>
</ftp>
```

do you have any suggestion to try for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this by windows bat file which was helpful. 
I created 2 file and placed @ D:/build/scripts/ 
 1) uploadFile.bat 
 2) uploadFile.ftp

I added below piece in my build.xml

```
<target name="ftpUpload" > 
         <exec executable="cmd" dir="D:/build/scripts/">
         <arg value="/C" />
         <arg value="uploadFile.bat" />                      
         </exec> 
    </target>
```

Inside my uploadFile.bat

```
ftp -i -s:uploadFile.ftp
pause
```

Inside my uploadFile.ftp i added

```
open 10.190.66.21
build
diet4pizz@
binary
put D:\build\scripts\test\*-test-*
disconnect
quit
```

And it was a success!!..
Thank you